# Insert a mean record in sas using proc sql

Tags: sas, aggregate-functions, union-all

I want to insert a record of mean into the data set according the identifier variable. The data set is like DS1 and I want to insert a variable if we have more than one pair of a-b values. Such as the target data set would be like DS2. Thanks my friends.

```
data DS1;
input a b c;
cards;
1 2 23
1 2 43
1 2 23
1 3 55
1 4 48
2 1 43
2 1 56
2 2 34
;
run;


data DS2;
input a b c;
cards;
1 2 23
1 2 43
1 2 23
1 2 27.66
1 3 55
1 4 48
2 1 43
2 1 56
2 1 44.5
2 2 34
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why SQL? If you're going to request a specific solution it's good to know why.  Here's two methods, one uses a data step and the other is SQL. Essentially the SQL solution calculates the values and UNION ALL appends them into the data set. The DATA STEP calculates the values as it passes through the data set, requiring only one pass through the data, and maintaining the order of the original data set.

```
data want_datastep;
set ds1;
by a b;
retain sum count;
if first.b then do;
    sum=0;
    count=0;
end;

sum=sum+c;
count+1;

if last.b and not first.b then do;
    output;
    c=sum/count;
    output;
end;
else output;
run;


proc sql;
create table want_sql as
select * from 
(select ds1.* from ds1 as ds1
union all
(select ds1_x.a, ds1_x.b, mean(ds1_x.c) as c
from ds1 as ds1_x
group by ds1_x.a, ds1_x.b
having count(ds1_x.b)>1))
order by a, b, c;
quit;
```